# Was Aqours created to rotate out μ’S?

Tags: love-live

After watching some live shows of Aqours, it seems to me that LL-Sunshine is doing what boy bands do all the time:

- Rotate the aging members out and replace them with younger ones.

I came across [this interesting piece of news](http://www.lovelive-anime.jp/otonokizaka/worldwide/news.php#2019):

> 2016/02/29
> 　“μ’S FINAL LOVE LIVE! ～μ’SIC FOREVER♪♪♪♪♪♪♪♪♪”
> THE LIVE CONCERT FROM LOVE LIVE! 　
> TO BE STREAMED LIVE IN THEATERS IN ASIA AND OSEANIA[sic]! – UPDATED!

Were Aqours created to replace the aging μ’S?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so Eri is going to try and answering this.

You do remember that by the end of Love Live anime, μ's disbanded, right? It was because us, the third years graduated from Ootonokizaka. μ's is a 'school idol' idol group. So it would not make sense if the members are not school idol. But if μ's was to keep going, then it would have to recruit new members to replace us the third years. Like Honoka said, and what we all agreed, it would not be μ's if it was not us nine. Therefore, the only option was to disband.

As for Aquors, they are like our sister group. Aquors is like what NMB48 is to AKB48. Although the relationship between μ's and Aquors is not that close since they are they were founded after μ's disbanded. They are a whole different group compared to ours. They are not replacement for μ's. **μ's is irreplaceable and will always lives on in our hearts and our fans' hearts.**

It's true that they did take some inspiration from μ's, and I can say that we are happy that they did. But, while they too are school idols, they have their own style, and their own music. They worked hard for the sake of their own fans.

Therefore please do support them as well.