# What Idol Groups in Love Live have real life counterparts?

Tags: love-live

According to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36807/was-aquors-created-to-rotate-out-%CE%BC-s), both μ's and Aquors are real life groups.

So, I am wondering what other groups that are mentioned in *Love Live! School Idol Project* and *Love Live! Sunshine!!* are also based off real life idol groups.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ARISE also has a real life group. But they are not active. They formed only for the anime but held no concerts like u's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japan, they are generally called as *seiyuu unit* ([Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A3%B0%E5%84%AA%E3%83%A6%E3%83%8B%E3%83%83%E3%83%88#.E5.A5.B3.E6.80.A7.E5.A3.B0.E5.84.AA.E3.81.AE.E3.81.BF.E3.81.AE.E3.83.A6.E3.83.8B.E3.83.83.E3.83.88)) when a music/acting unit (group) consists of voice actors. For a special case where a group also works as a real-life idol, it is called *seiyuu idol unit*.

According to the Wikipedia, there are 3 units, but only 2 are *seiyuu idol units*:

- A-RISE (created for *Love Live!*, no live event/talk)

  - Kira Tsubasa: Sakuragawa Megu
  - Toudou Erena: Matsunaga Maho
  - Yuuki Anju: Ohashi Ayuru
- μ's (created in 2010 for *Love Live!*, 6 live events, 4 live talks, 18 guest appearances)

  - Kousaka Honoka (**Leader/Printemps**): Nitta Emi
  - Ayase Eli (**Bi Bi**): Nanjo Yoshino
  - Minami Kotori (Printemps): Uchida Aya
  - Sonoda Umi (**lily white**): Mimori Suzuko
  - Hoshizora Rin (lily white/NikoRinPana): Iida Riho
  - Nishikino Maki (Bi Bi): Pile
  - Toujou Nozomi (lily white): Kusuda Aina
  - Koizumi Hanayo (Printemps/NikoRinPana): Kubo Yurika
  - Yazawa Nico (Bi Bi/**NikoRinPana**): Tokui Sora
- Aquors (created in 2015 for *Love Live! Sunshine!!*, 2 live events, 5 live talks, 3 guest appearances):

  - Takami Chika (**Leader/CYaRon!**/Gu~RinPa): Inami Anju
  - Sakurauchi Riko (**Guilty Kiss**): Aida Rikako
  - Matsuura Kanan (**AZALEA**): Suwa Nanaka
  - Kurosawa Dia (AZALEA/**Gu~RinPa**): Komiya Arisa
  - Watanabe You (CYaRon!): Saitou Shuka
  - Tsushima Yoshiko (Guilty Kiss/Gu~RinPa): Kobayashi Aika
  - Kunikida Hanamaru (AZALEA): Takatsuki Kanako
  - Ohara Mari (Guilty Kiss): Suzuki Aina
  - Kurosawa Ruby (CYaRon!): Furihata Ai

Comment: Not sure if [Saint Snow](http://love-live.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_Snow) is considered as *seiyuu unit* or not. It's not mentioned on Wikipedia.